# minSDK version in Android Manifest issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've got a little problem with my project. 
Few months ago everything was ok (project can be compile and run without any problems). Ater that when i try to compile it (without any changes - only android studio updates), below errors show me up:

```
E:\Android\Android\android studio projects\Sklepik\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(8, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library E:\Android\Android\android studio projects\Sklepik\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library E:\Android\Android\android studio projects\Sklepik\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage
```

My manifest looks like:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"
        />
```

and gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
```

Even when i change in both setcion minSdk to 14 or add overrideLibrary nothing happens. 
How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `play services` with version `10.2.0` that works on higher SDK version (min 14). You can either set 14 as min SDK version in your app or choose a lower play services version that is compatible with skd version 9.

Comment: Here is the official link explaining same https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I try to use 7.8.0 version of play services but when i compile project, studio show me a lot of below problems : Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.

Comment: I don't know why this project was good few months ago and right now i've got a lot of trouble:(

Comment: It is because yur dependencies are not mutually compatible. What is the problem is upgrading the version to 14. Do you really want to support devices with Android 9.

Comment: Nayan ofcourse my target sdk is 17. I will try to rebuild me project and use newest version 10.2.0 of play services. Thanks for help